# How to show $ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{2x} - 3x^2=+\infty$

Tags: limits

It is easy to see that:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}  e^{2x}-3x^2=+\infty
$$
But how to show/prove it? Maybe with L'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma**: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{3x²}{e^{2x}} = 0$$

**Proof**: Apply l'Hopital's rule twice $\quad \square$

Now, notice $$e^{2x} - 3x² = \frac{e^{2x}-3x²}{e^{2x}}e^{2x} = \left(1 - \frac{3x²}{e^{2x}}\right)e^{2x}$$

and hence

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (e^{2x} - 3x²) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{3x²}{e^{2x}}\right)e^{2x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{3x²}{e^{2x}}\right)\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{2x}$$

$$ = \left(\lim_{x \to \infty} 1 - \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{3x²}{e^{2x}}\right)\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{2x} = (1 -0) \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{2x} = 1. (+ \infty) = + \infty$$

Note that the rules: "limit of a sum is sum of the limits" and "limit of a product is product of the limits" can only be used because the limits in the right hand sides always exist (by the lemma).

Comment: I've a doubt about the application of H-rule in this way. Please check your answer.

Comment: 3x^2/e^(2x) has the form infinity/infinity. Not sure what you are talking about..

Comment: I'm not at all  sure that in general you can calculate limit is such way dividing the terms and applying H-rule only to a part. But it's only a dubt that I have.

Comment: There is really no problem here.

Comment: If you think there is a problem, feel free to provide a counterexample.

Comment: Morover you don't need to use H-rule as $3x^2/e^{2x}\to0$. I could ask as question here in the forum if you agree.

Comment: You don't need it, but you can apply it here, and since the OP is allowed to use it, I don't see a problem.

Comment: In my opinion you can't apply H-rule at a single part of a limit, in this case the final result is ok but it's not a good way in general. Let's try to post the question?

Comment: I will edit my answer a bit. I left some steps out. Hold on a second.

Comment: Here you go. I typed out some more steps. What exactly is bothering you ?

Comment: Now it's clear! Thanks for the patience.

Comment: No problem :) You can always give an upvote ;)

Comment: It' more than deserved!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For $x>0$ you can use $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}x^k \geq 1+x+\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3$